# df.index vs df["index"] after resetting index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "value": [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]})
print(df1)
print("-------------------------")
print(df1.reset_index())
print("-------------------------")
print(df1.reset_index().index)
print("-------------------------")
print(df1.reset_index()["index"])
```

produces the output

```
   value
0      1
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      2
5      2
-------------------------
   index  value
0      0      1
1      1      1
2      2      1
3      3      2
4      4      2
5      5      2
-------------------------
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=6, step=1)
-------------------------
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

I am wondering why `print(df1.reset_index().index)` and
`print(df1.reset_index()["index"])` prints different things in this case? The latter prints the "index" column, while the former prints the indices.

If we want to access the reset indices (the column), then it seems we have to use brackets?

Answer (score 1):

The [`.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.index.html#pandas.DataFrame.index) attribute in a pandas DataFrame will always point to the Index (row label) of the DataFrame not a column named "index".

> If we want to access the reset indices (the column), then it seems we
> have to use brackets?

Yes, or you can assign a name when reseting the index for example:

```
df1.reset_index(names='the_index').the_index

# 0    0
# 1    1
# 2    2
# 3    3
# 4    4
# 5    5
# Name: the_index, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

It does this because you are printing different things:

```
print(df1.reset_index().index)
```

is the same as:

```
df = df1.reset_index()
print(df.index)
```

This firstly adds an Id index to the dataframe then prints the actual index of the df.

```
print(df1.reset_index()["index"])
```

is the equivalent of

```
df = df1.reset_index()
print(df["index"])
```

It firstly adds an Id index to the dataframe but keeps both "index" and "values" columns. It then prints the Column named "Index" (which is NOT the index of the df)

If you want to make the "index" column the index, you must use:

```
df = df1.set_index("index")
```

Answer (score 0):

Several things happened. First, when you don't specify and index, `pandas` uses a `RangeIndex` object as a virtual index of the dataframe. The dataframe is a collection of numpy arrays which are naturally indexed from 0, 1, 2, and etc. Since `RangeIndex` is just 0, 1, etc... it doesn't actually create its values in memory. Had you printed the index of the original `df1`, it would be a `RangeIndex`, just like `df1.reset_index().index`.

`reset_index` has an optional `drop` parameter. By default, pandas will take the existing index and turn it into a column of the dataframe. This was a `RangeIndex` object but it had to be expanded into a realized column to fit with the other columns in the df. Had you included `drop=True`, there would be no "index" column.

When you reset the index, dataframes always have to have some index and the default is that virtual `RangeIndex` you see.

DataFrames have a shortcut where *some* columns can be addressed by attribute name rather than item (the square brackets). But, if the column name doesn't meet python's attribute naming rules or if it clashes with an existing attribute, you can't reference it that way. `.index` is the dataframe index so if you happen to also have a column "index", you need to access it via the square bracket item protocol.

One could argue that pandas should never have allowed the attribute access path because it can't be used consistently. *I* wouldn't argue that (except I totally would).